# Не работает изменение дополнительных параметров у фона "тела"

Tags: javascript

написал такой код:

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'url(desktop/background.jpg)');
```

Но, когда я пытался использовать:

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'url(desktop/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed');
```

То ничего не работало. Где ошибка?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь в `background-image` впихнуть и `background-position` и `background-repeat` и прочее. Для таких конструкций используйте общее свойство `background`.

Answer (score 0):

background и background-image имеют разные css аргументы

```js
$('body').css('background', 'url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/7919/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350") no-repeat center center fixed');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```